# How to keep track of the index of a numpy array element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to iterate over the items of a numpy array using a for loop. Is there a way to keep track of the index of the current item of the iteration (other than initializing a counter before the loop and increment it inside the loop)?

```
myArray = [4 5 6 7]

for item in myArray:
    print(index of item)
```

What I would like to get is (keeping in mind that this is a numpy array, not a list)

```
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use `enumerate`:

```
myArray = [4, 5, 6, 7]

for i,item in enumerate(myArray):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was looking for. I achieved this with a pandas dataframe using `for index, row in df.iterrows():` and was looking to do the same thing for an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([6,5,7,0,1,3,4])

for index in range(a.shape[0]):  # use range with nparray.shape[0] to get the size
    print(index) # you can do a[index] to get the value
```

this outputs :

```py
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Works well but not the right way of doing it since I am trying to access the items inside the loop as well; not just printing the index. But thanks for the answer!